# Converting statements into expressions

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for ideas on how to convert code into expressions in C# for Unity. We have this basic list of statements:

Simple statements:

- assignment: A:= A + 5
- call: CLEARSCREEN()
- return: return 5;

Compound statements:

- if-statement: if A > 3 then WRITELN(A) else WRITELN("NOT YET"); end
- switch-statement: switch (c) { case 'a': alert(); break; case 'q': quit(); break; }
- while-loop: while NOT EOF DO begin READLN end
- do-loop: do { computation(&i); } while (i < 10);
- for-loop: for A:=1 to 10 do WRITELN(A) end

The expressions that replace these statements should be chained, for example using And operators (expression1 && expression2 && .. expresionN), so the order of execution is respected. Also the ?: operator is allowed.

**Assignment**

If we have this statement:

```
int a = 100;
```

Can be converted into:

```
((a = 100) == a)
```

Yet not perfect, since the comparison is not optimized in IL code. I also tried:

```
((a = 100) is int)
```

This throws a warning, the comparison is optimized but the assignment is removed too. Any other idea that only produces the assignment in IL code?

**Call**

A call is automatically converted into a expression, right? Well, not exactly. How do you chain a void function?

Also if you pass parameters by reference, you will need a variable external to the expression.

**Return**

This one is directly converted:

```
return 5;

(5)
```

**If and Switch statements**

The ?: operator replaces them:

```
if (a == 5) { b = "yes"; } else { b = "no"; }

((a == 5) ? "yes" : "no")
```

**While, Do and For loops**

Loop unwinding could be used here, if the number of iterations is fixed.

Comment: You mean using expression trees?

Comment: Expression trees? I can give it a try, but I'm not sure this is fully supported in all the Unity platforms, not from what I have read. Also the code looks bulkier than using simple operations. Not sure how it is optimized by the compiler, could there be any gain against basic operators? Also adds another library, might be heavy for mobile devices and such. I'll investigate more, but might not be what I'm looking for.

Comment: I mean, what you're doing can be done using expression trees (as described). But I'm maybe a little confused about the question. Are you just trying to compile expressions into runnable code? That sounds like you want expression trees. You can do it with pure IL, but you'll find that that's an exercise in tedium until you get a lot of practice. Expression trees at least make sense (after a short learning curve). And of course, Expression trees *compile*, so it's way quicker than reflection.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple, just to replace several lines of code with a single one... or even smaller, a single expression. Expression trees sound like a good solution, thanks for mentioning them, but in practice, in Unity, these might introduce other problems. I'll have to learn more about them, make tests, read generated IL code, profile, and measure player size to find out if these are actually worth. Instead there is no doubt standard expressions using the basic language operators will provide what I need now. I just need to come up with conversions from statements.